Bent ductwork at vent?
Am I looking at ducting that’s folded back into the vent in this picture? There was a return register before that just sat on top, and I went to replace it with an adjustable register but since it has to fit inside the vent instead of just on top, it won’t fit with this bent frame. Seems like an insulation layer between that’s ripping when I fold it up.
Edit: air flows out of this vent, so I’m installing a register that has some depth to it. This is an internal duct path, no external walls. House is from the 70s.




Maybe [edit] to include a pic of the new register you're trying to install. In general, though, I'd suggest that (since this is a return), you just bend (or snip if necessary) the sheet metal to make your new register fit. Those flaps sticking up will slow some air flow, but since air is going in here (not blowing out), it will flow somewhat smoothly over those. It almost looks like the installer left the duct long, put some sort of frame in there, then bent the metal over to hold the frame in place, instead of using screws.

I'm not very familiar with insulated ducts, but those tabs appear to be there to retain the insulation panels. Why is this duct insulated? Does it pass through unconditioned space?

Will edit for clarification. Air flows out, so I’m installing a register. There was a return grille there before by mistake. This is all an internal path.

@Ish, the ducts are made from insulated fibreglass board, Called, not surprisingly, "Duct Board".  They make up the body of the duct, or make a box for flexible duct to terminate in.  The metal is just a "ring" around the edge to support the register and supply a surface for a metal screw to anchor the register.

Your unstated question must be, "How to get the register to fit?".
The new register must be the proper size. The size of your duct box may not be a common size, hence the grille was covering it before. You may need to do some shopping online rather than the local big box stores.
An issue that is evident, is that new drywall has been installed and it does not  cover to the top edge of the duct.  This must be remedied.
you may be able to tape the gap with aluminium ducting tape.
You can add a small piece of drywall and tape and mud it. ( The drywall is not taped so this can be done.
You may want to remove the metal duct ring and size a new ring for the size of the drywall hole. This cam make the register installation easier, however you may need to get in the attic to seal the new metal properly.
